# iis Cpu is on 95% usage with very little users - on production

Tags: iis, cpu-usage

I have a web site and I am using iis as my web server. I noticed that on production server, the cpu reaches 95% usage pretty fast with very little users. this behaviour I don't see on my developement server. I am using visual studio to develop and iis as my local web server as well.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

How much big traffic you have on production comparing to development server? How their parameters compare? Before starting a deep analysis of the application itself, I would identify all the infrastructure and environmental differences. Sometime such problems happens because of some other software, like antivirus software running in the background...

Nevertheless, because it sounds rather as a application problem, I would first check *Event Viewer* for errors. Then I would start from monitoring a few Performance Counters to correlate `% Processor Time` counter with `Current Connections`, `Available Memory`, `# of Exceps Thrown / sec`, `% Time in GC` and so on. This kind of behavior usually has a reason from the list:

- **excessive loops usage** due to some logic error, like calling the same service again and again, trying to load or parse malfunctioned file etc. This can be analyzed with dump analysis (look below).
- high CPU usage due to **Garbage Collector** - when memory usage is extensive (or there is a memory leak even) GC may start to consume more and more CPU fighting with the memory shortage. You will see this with memory-related performance counters.
- a **considerable amount of exceptions thrown** (for example due to some environmental problems like network unavailability, production data difference) can also consume a lot of CPU. *Event Viewer* and exception-related performance counters (as they can be handled silently by your application) should be a indicator here.

To further analyze your application, I suggest to make a full memory dump during high CPU usage. You can do that with [Debug Diag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40336) tool. Please refer [this IIS troubleshooting guide](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool) for details.